# How to specify the arrow length in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I've a small problem in Tikz. I try to draw arrows within 4 dimensions. Every arrow should have equal  length.
My implementation right now works with coordinates. There is a rectangle with a center point and in each direction a point at the edge. I'd like to draw an arrow from the center in each direction with the same size.
Right now I draw between the center and this construct:  `($(center)!0.5!(borderpoint)$)`.
The problem with that is, it differs between the short an width edges but I'd like to have the same length in every direction.

Example:

```
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!0.5!(0,1.5)$);
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!0.5!(6,1.5)$);
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!0.5!(3,3)$);
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!0.5!(3,0)$);
\shade[shading=ball, ball color=black!90] (3,1.5) circle (0.25em);
```

[image: Arrows]

I wish to: *draw* an *arrow from Startpoint* in *direction of DestPoint* for an *length of X*.  :))

Comment: Related Question: [Specify the length of the arrow in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205040/specify-the-length-of-the-arrow-in-tikz/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify which is the `length` of the arrow in this way:

```
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!1cm!(0,1.5)$);
```

where the `length` is `1cm`.

Here is the revised example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!1cm!(0,1.5)$);
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!1cm!(6,1.5)$);
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!1cm!(3,3)$);
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!1cm!(3,0)$);
\shade[shading=ball, ball color=black!90] (3,1.5) circle (0.25em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

You can find more information on the `calc` library on the documentation (13.5 Coordinate Calculations, pgfmanual version October 25, 2010).

---

A quickest implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\arrowlength
\setlength{\arrowlength}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
\foreach \destination in 
{{0,1.5},{6,1.5},{3,3},{3,0}}
\draw[->, thick] (3,1.5) -- ($(3,1.5)!\arrowlength!(\destination)$);
\shade[shading=ball, ball color=black!90] (3,1.5) circle (0.25em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah ok,this is strange. i tried this befor and i did not work at all. with this knowledge now i modified my graphic. i found that if i do something like this: \pgfmathsetmacro{\arrowSize}{1cm} it won't work. I'll try a bit more, thanks so far.

Comment: No, you should use `\pgfmathsetlength{\arrowlength}{1cm}`; in the _quickest implementation_ you can absolutely substitute `\setlength{\arrowlength}{1cm}
` with `\pgfmathsetlength{\arrowlength}{1cm}` without problems.

Comment: very cool. thank you very much. daily improvements. i like :)