# Specify the length of the arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This should be an easy one. Instead of specifying where the start and finish of the arrow should be, I want to specify how long the arrow should be. It might sound like the same thing, but when you have nodes of unknown lengths between several arrows, it is not the same thing, because I'm no longer sure what the exact starting point of the arrow is when there is a node before it.

This example should make it clearer. What I want is a set length for each arrow, and the nodes should simply be placed where the arrows start and end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[left] at (0,0) (Step 1) {Step 1};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (Step 1) -- (2,0);
    \node[right] at (2,0) (Step 2) {Step 2};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (Step 2) -- (4,0);
    \node[right] at (4,0) (Step 3) {Step 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS. I know there's a question with the same question as this one ([How to specify the arrow length in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76277/how-to-specify-the-arrow-length-in-tikz)), but it's way more complicated than what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to specify the length you can use `++`. So, if you to draw an arrow that is `3cm` long use `++(3.0cm,0)` as shown in the red arrow.

If your desire is to only draw fixed length arrows and place nodes following the arrows, let `tikz` figure out the location of the nodes by using `node` (*not* `\node`) as part of the `\draw` (as opposed to a separate `\node`).  Be careful to start the drawing from one end of the node (below I used `east`). Otherwise the center of the `node` is used.

[image]

### Notes:

- This is probably the simplest way to specify a length, as long as you want horizontal, or vertical lines.  If you want to specify the length *along* a certain vector than you should refer to [How to specify the arrow length in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76277/how-to-specify-the-arrow-length-in-tikz)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\FixedLengthArrow}{2,0}
\begin{document}
The black arrows are \SI{2}{\centi\meter} long:\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[left] at (0,0) (Step 1) {Step 1};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (Step 1.east) -- ++(\FixedLengthArrow)
        node[right] (Step 2) {NeXT Step 2};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (Step 2.east) -- ++(\FixedLengthArrow)
        node[right]  (Step 3) {Step 3};
        
    %% To draw a line which is 3cm long
    \draw [ultra thick, red, ->] (0,-1) -- ++(3.0cm,0) node [above, pos=0.5] {This is \SI{3}{\centi\meter}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Playing around with this, it seems to set the length of the arrow _plus_ any following node, since the arrow in ``\node[left] at (0,0) (Step 1) {Steeeeeeeep 1}; \draw [very thick, ->] (Step 1) -- ++(2cm,0) node[right] (Step 2) {Step 2};`` is much shorter than the arrow in ``\node[left] at (0,0) (Step 1) {Step 1}; \draw [very thick, ->] (Step 1) -- ++(2cm,0) node[right] (Step 2) {Step 2};``. So how do I put nodes between set arrow lengths as in my ``MWE``?

Comment: @Sverre: Have updated answer to show how to do that.

Comment: But as mentioned in my initial comment, the lengths of the arrows are the same here only because the nodes are of equal length. If you change one of the nodes, e.g. ``{Step 1}`` to ``{Steeeeeeep 1}``, you'll see that the arrow shortens. So the length specification ``{2cm,0}`` seems to _include_ the node.

Comment: @Sverre: My apologizes for missing that detail... Let me know if it is better now...

Comment: I tried the ++(3.0cm,0) in Tikz graph but odd semicolon missing err. The edges show up right in MWE [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320239/edges-getting-super-small-in-tikz-graph-apparent-inheritance-issue) but get super small when added to a larger document. Anyway to force the edges to stay in certain length or increase the lengths somehow?

Comment: @hhh: Not sure I understand this comment, but it looks like you answer your own question in the link provided so am assuming this is resolved.

Comment: Fixed arrows go to the right in this example is there a way to change direction?

Comment: @ömerkoçhan: Instead of `->`, using the `<-` option to the `\draw` should work. If not, please post a new question.  And to have the arrows go in _both_ directions use `<->`.