# Edges getting super small in Tikz Graph, apparent inheritance issue?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I can get the MWE working but when I insert that Tikz graph into a large document, the edges get super small -- some inheritance? How can I make the edges stay in the right size in tikz graph?

**Goal and its MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}

\tikz \graph {
1 -- 1{,}4 -- 1{,}3 -- 1{,}2 -- 1{,}4{} -- 1{};
2 -- 2{,}4 -- 2{,}3 -- 2{,}1 -- 2{,}4{} -- 2{};
3 -- 3{,}1 -- 3{,}2 -- 3{,}4 -- 3{,}5 -- 3{};
4 -- 4{,}1 -- 4{,}2 -- 4{,}3 -- 4{,}1{} -- 4{,}2{} -- 4{};
5 -- 5{} -- 5{,}3 -- 5{}{} -- 5{}{}{};

1{,}4 -- [bend right] 4{,}1;
1{,}3 -- 3{,}1;
2{,}4{} -- 4{,}2{};
1{,}4{} -- [bend right] 4{,}1{};
3{,}5 -- [bend right] 5{,}3;
2{,}4 -- 4{,}2;
};

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Result** where edges super small

> [image]

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate? I don't undestand what you mean by edges here.

Comment: @RunarTrollet edges are between the numbers: in the result, the edges become just dots because the node settings make the nodes (the numbers) become too large -- so I need to find settings by which I can change the size of the node smaller. I found a way to do it with `inner sep` but missing small font size on the nodes.

Comment: the MWE is supposed to be an example _of the problem_ can't you add text in from your bigger document until you get the bad result and post the example document

Answer (score 1):

The `inner sep` settings are somehow inherited from node settings so making them to null. I updated like this and it is getting a bit better but the font size in the nodes (the numbers) is still somewhat too large.

```
\tikz [inner sep=0pt]\graph {
1 -- 1{,}4 -- 1{,}3 -- 1{,}2 -- 1{,}4{} -- 1{};
2 -- 2{,}4 -- 2{,}3 -- 2{,}1 -- 2{,}4{} -- 2{};
3 -- 3{,}1 -- 3{,}2 -- 3{,}4 -- 3{,}5 -- 3{};
4 -- 4{,}1 -- 4{,}2 -- 4{,}3 -- 4{,}1{} -- 4{,}2{} -- 4{};
5 -- 5{} -- 5{,}3 -- 5{}{} -- 5{}{}{};

1{,}4 -- [bend right] 4{,}1;
1{,}3 -- 3{,}1;
2{,}4{} -- 4{,}2{};
1{,}4{} -- [bend right] 4{,}1{};
3{,}5 -- [bend right] 5{,}3;
2{,}4 -- 4{,}2;
};
}
```